# R - "apply" for 2 matrices

Tags: r, apply

I am doing an R assignment and I have to write a function that does what `dist.xyz` does.

```
dist.xyz(a, b = NULL, all.pairs=FALSE)
```

a and b are matrices of numbers and the function computes the distances between corresponding rows of
‘a’ and ‘b’.

I tried a for loop (as below) but it takes too long and "apply" only allows us to do operation on 1 matrix at a time.

```
 dis = vector()
 for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    append(dis,sqrt(sum((a[i,] - b[i,]) ^ 2)))
 }
```

Is there some way to "apply" to two matrices?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to learn how to create an example (and this is especially true for homework questions). At the moment we have no idea what expData1 or expData2 look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier if you had example data. But here's my take. This isn't a general solution for '"apply" for 2 matrices'. However, in your case, you only need apply for a single matrix a-b, since the element-wise difference of each row is the first thing you take. Then apply square, sum, and square root to each row to obtain your result.

```
set.seed(7)   # just to ensure reproducible results

rowDist<-function(a,b) {
   apply(a-b,1,function(x)sqrt(sum(x^2)))
}

a<-matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)
b<-matrix(rnorm(25),5,5)

rowDist(a,b)
#[1] 2.716251 2.685056 3.699462 2.125998 3.437412
```